# joomla 1.5.26 system message AcePolls vote not coming on same page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have joomla version 1.15.26. I have used AcePolls components http://www.joomace.net/downloads/acepolls/acepolls-for-joomla-15

In my index.php I have code like :

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

My problem is that when I vote for poll the message from controller, not displaying on same page. But when I visit other page, this message is there.

I couldn't find where it the problem, as in my localhost it's working fine, but on live server it's not working properly.

As I understand system messages are stored as in queue in joomla. But here it's queuing but displaying on another reload (not on same page reload, on other page visit).

My controller:

```
function vote() {

        $mainframe  = JFactory::getApplication();
        $poll_id    = JRequest::getInt('id', 0);
        $option_id  = JRequest::getInt('voteid', 0);
        $poll       =& JTable::getInstance('Poll', 'Table');
        $item_id    = JRequest::getInt('itemid');

        if (!$poll->load($poll_id) || $poll->published != 1) {
            JError::raiseWarning(404, JText::_('ALERTNOTAUTH'));
            return;
        }

        $cookieName = JUtility::getHash($mainframe->getName().'poll'.$poll_id);
        $voted = JRequest::getVar($cookieName, '0', 'COOKIE', 'INT');

        if ($voted || !$option_id) { 
            if ($voted) {
                $msg = JText::_('COM_ACEPOLLS_ALREADY_VOTED');
                $tom = "error";
            }

            if (!$option_id){
                $msg = JText::_('COM_ACEPOLLS_NO_SELECTED');
                $tom = "error";
            }
        }
        else { 
            require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'models'.DS.'poll.php');
            $model = new AcepollsModelPoll();

            if ($model->vote($poll_id, $option_id)) {
                //Set cookie showing that user has voted
                setcookie($cookieName, '1', time() + 60*$poll->lag);
            }

            $msg = JText::_('COM_ACEPOLLS_THANK_YOU');
            $tom = "";

            if (JFactory::getUser()->id != 0) {
                JPluginHelper::importPlugin('acepolls');
                $dispatcher =& JDispatcher::getInstance();
                $dispatcher->trigger('onAfterVote', array($poll, $option_id));
            }
        }

        // set Itemid id for links
        $menu    = &JSite::getMenu();
        $items   = $menu->getItems('link', 'index.php?option=com_acepolls');

        $itemid  = isset($items[0]) ? '&Itemid='.$items[0]->id : '';

        if(!$itemid)
            $itemid = '&Itemid='.$item_id;

        $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_acepolls&view=poll&id='. $poll_id.':'.$poll->alias.$itemid, false), $msg, $tom);

    }
```

Let me know if any other information is required.
Thanks in advance.